# can not mark as read my incoming whatsapp message using whatsapp business api

Tags: python, api, whatsapp

Here's what I've done. I'm using Python programming language.

```
res = requests.put(
    url='https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/messages/wamid.HBgMOTE4NzgwNDk1ODA0FQIAEhggQkU2OURGQUYyMzdCNDlBRkQ1QUI4RERBNDdENDBBOEIA', 
    header = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer my-auth-token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }, 
    data=json.dumps({"status": "read"})
)

print(res.json())
```

Output:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Unknown path components: /wamid.HBgMOTE4NzgwNDk1ODA0FQIAEhggQkU2OURGQUYyMzdCNDlBRkQ1QUI4RERBNDdENDBBOEIA', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 2500, 'fbtrace_id': 'A6f8nCvHOSXSZcAGmevCGeJ'}}
```

Comment: Try this: `url='https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me/messages/message-id?=BgMOTE4NzgwNDk1ODA0FQIAEhggQkU2OURGQUYyMzdCNDlBRkQ1QUI4RERTBNDdENDBBOEIA'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/mark-message-as-read) the url is supposed to look like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages
```

You seem to be missing `PHONE_NUMBER_ID` in its correct place, and seem to have `wamid...` which doesn't seem to be needed here. I also notice that your request body is missing the required data:

```
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"status": "read",  <- you only seem to have this
"message_id": "MESSAGE_ID"
```

Also, the docs show a POST request while you seem to be using a PUT request. If you solve all these problems it should start working.

Comment: thanks it worked, but it requires `wamid.` at the start of message id.